# Using WCF Web Service to output database information on client side using c#

Tags: c#, json, web-services, wcf

I have created a WCF Web Service using this walk through:

http://mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/Services/WebServices-Page2.htm

It returns data from a local SQL Server.  The WCF Web Service takes a string parameter, and returns it back, as a string in JSON format.

I have now created a client website where i want to use the WCF Services as my data source to output the information in the database through a grid view or something similar.  How do i do this?  I assume i have to use some c#.

Service.cs:

```
public class Service : IService
{
private object cds;
public List<cdInfo> GetCDinfo()
{
    try
    {
        CdDataClassesDataContext dc = new CdDataClassesDataContext();
        List<cdInfo> results = new List<cdInfo>();

        foreach (cd cD in dc.cds)
        {
            results.Add(new cdInfo()
            {
                Id = cD.Id.ToString(),
                artist = cD.artist,
                genre = cD.genre,
                title = cD.title,
                date = cD.date
            });}
        return results;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //  Return any exception messages back to the Response header
        OutgoingWebResponseContext response = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;
        response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        response.StatusDescription = ex.Message.Replace("\r\n", "");
        return null;}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this link will help you in consuming WCF service.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412178(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: you can also see this link too. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42643/Creating-and-Consuming-Your-First-WCF-Service

Comment: I am struggling to get the data from public List<cdInfo> GetCDinfo().  Do you know how to call it in c#?

Comment: @jordan There are multiple ways to access wcf services you need to create an endpoint and channel factory to access it, follow the steps in article mentioned and you will be able to access it